# Filling a list with position number

Tags: python, list, function, factorial

The factorial series is defined as follows:

```
F(0) = 1
F(n) = N * F(n-1) (for n>1)
```

Write a recursive function `factorial(N)` that computes the Nth term of the factorial
series and returns it. Write a program that:

1. Asks the user to enter an integer `Q`
2. Creates a list of `Q` integers
3. Fills all the list with, in position number `j`, the the `jth` term of the factorial
   series, as computed by the `factorial()` function
4. Prints the content of the list.

Here is my attempt:

```
def factorial(N):
    if N<=1:
        return 1
    elif N>=1:
        return int(N*factorial(N-1))
print (factorial(3))
import random
Q=int(input("please enter a value"))
range1 = range(0,Q,1)
for i in range1:
    print(i,end="")
factorial (j)
```

I'm not too sure how to complete it. I don't understand what it means by " Fills all the list with, in position number j, the the jth term of the factorial series, as computed by the factorial() function "

Comment: Please post your attempt and what exactly you're struggling with

Comment: I dont see a question?

Comment: Im not to sure how to complete it. I don't understand what it means by " Fills all the list with, in position number j, the the jth term of the factorial series, as computed by the factorial() function "

Comment: So if you have Q input of 3, you will have a list of 3 items, indexed from 0, 1, 2. for each index position in that list you should populate it with the factorial value of that position. However for clarity you should ask who ever gave the assignemnt

Comment: Thanks @Chris Doyle however I don't understand how do I populate the index position

Answer (score 0):

Its still not exactly clear the problem statement so maybe you should go back to the person who assigned you the problem and ask them to clarify. However, my take on it is that you have a factorial function. And ask the user for a integer value `Q`. You then need to create a list of the factorial result for each value in the range of `Q`

```py
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n >= 1:
        return n * factorial(n - 1)
    else:
        return 0

#get the value from the user
q = int(input("enter an integer: "))


#verbose method which first creates empty Q length list then fills it
qlist = ['']*q
for j,_ in enumerate(qlist):
    qlist[j] = factorial(j)
print(qlist)


#list comprehension to build and populate the list in one go
qlist = [factorial(i) for i in range(q+1)]
print(qlist)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
entered integer: 10
[0, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880]
[0, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880]
```